# Saving multiple api calls in a json file in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm trying to save a stock ticker results of an API query with a loop. I can save to a file, but as it loops, it writes over the previous json file. Below is the code.

```
import json
import requests
from ticker import tickers
from tokens import token

i = 0
while i < len(tickers):
 data = requests.get("https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/" + tickers[i] + ".US?api_token="+ token).json()
 i = i + 1

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
  json.dump(data, outfile)

#tickers = ['APPL', 'MSFT', 'BAC']
```

This is mostly for testing and will eventually be saved to a server database

Comment: You could use `time.strftime` to add a time stamp to the filename.

Comment: How would I use that in my code?

Comment: You are overwriting `data` each time in the for loop, and then writing the content of `data` into your out file. In other words, you're only saving the last one to file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save a list rather the variable `data` in loop:

```
import json
import requests
from ticker import tickers
from tokens import token

data_list = []
i = 0
while i < len(tickers):
    data = requests.get("https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/" + tickers[i] + ".US?api_token="+ token).json()
    data_list.append(data)
    i = i + 1

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data_list, outfile)
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it needed append, just didn't know who to go about it.